# Fastest way to sort and get unique data - want last occurrence?

Tags: python, unique-index

Hi I have big dataset like this in Python:

```
data=[[2105,90],
      [2115,100],
      [2125,110],
      [2135,120],
      [2145,130],
      [2155,140],
      [2200,110],
      [2115,109],
      [2155,142]]
```

and I want a result where data is from the last occurrence. In the example above I want 2115=109 and 2155=142:

```
data=[[2105,90],
      [2115,109],
      [2125,110],
      [2135,120],
      [2145,130],
      [2155,142],
      [2200,110]]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Just send it all to a dict `dict(data)`

Comment: Is the dataset sorted?

Answer (score 3):

You can just put `data` in a dictionary:

```
>>> data
[[2105, 90], [2115, 100], [2125, 110], [2135, 120], [2145, 130], [2155, 140], [2200, 110], [2115, 109], [2155, 142]]
>>> dict(data)[2115]
109
>>> dict(data)[2155]
142
```

Dictionaries have unique keys. As more entries are added from the list, the *values* of existing *keys* get updated. This results in you getting the last occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to both statements above. I have 3 set of files with data. Each set have about one millions of files. In the example above I have 6 value from fileset1, 1 value from fileset2 and 1 value from fileset3. With the tip of dictionary the solution would be like this (I get data when a regular expression match):

```
value={}
for j in ['*1981*.txt','*1990*.txt','*1991*.txt']:
    files=glob.glob(j)
    files.sort()
    for file in files:
        inFile=open(file, 'r')
        for line in inFile:
            if cregexp2.match(line):
                a=cregexp2.findall(line)[0]
                value[a[0]]=a[1]
```

This is one solution which work but takes some time. Is there someone which have an idea of a better way?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Red Black BST's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) to store your info. This way, you only need to traverse a small number of nodes. This will be useful in most cases (because the tree keeps splitting into half).